# fetch или Promise.all не дожидается всех результатов

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hook

Пытаюсь вывести все имена по урлам, но на 64 имени оно перестаёт помещать имена в массив и возвращает их, а уже после вывода массива подгружает остальныне имена. (закоментированный console.log) Если очистить массив, на месте имён ничего нет, но если этого не делать (закоментировал) - видно урлы персонажей, вместо имён.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Весь код из useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {   
        const loadPlanets = async () => {
            try {
                let all_planets = [];
                for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                    const req = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page="+i);
                    if (req.ok) {
                        const res = await req.json();
                        res.results.forEach(async (r, ind) => {
                            const residents = r.residents;
                            const films = r.films;
                            /*res.results[ind].residents = [];
                            res.results[ind].films = [];*/
                            res.results[ind].residents = await loadNameOrTitle(residents);
                            res.results[ind].films = await loadNameOrTitle(films);
                            delete res.results.created;
                            delete res.results.edited;
                            delete res.results.url;

                        });
                        all_planets = all_planets.concat(res.results);
                    } else {
                        console.log(req.statusText);
                    }

                }
                set_objects(all_planets);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        const loadNameOrTitle = async (urls) => {
            return await Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
                try {
                    const req = await fetch(url);
                    if (req.ok) {
                        const res = await req.json();
                        //console.log(res.name || res.title);
                        return res.name || res.title;
                    } else {
                        console.log(req.statusText);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }));
        }
        loadPlanets();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Promise.all отлично работает, это forEach никак не дожидается завершения работы асинхронных функций, замените на обычный цикл for-of

Comment: @andreymal, блин, точно! Спасибо!